# Can I run AOSPExtended Android 10 ROM in a 16gb storage phone?

Tags: custom-roms, android-10

I have a Micromax canvas Q417 modeled phone whose last officially received system update was of Android 5.1 Lollipop and they too about 5 years ago. So I decided to install a custom ROM. After searching and researching, I found AOSPExtended Android 10 ROM perfect for me (here is the [link](https://downloads.aospextended.com/victara)). It is an old Motorola model ROM but the device specifications for this model and my model are the same except for one thing ie this phone comes in two variants, one with 16gb internal storage and another with 32. I have 16gb internal storage and after rains some parts on Reddit and Quora, I found that Android 10 updates take a lot of space probably miss than 16gb. The ROM download size in this link is about 400mb which so will I be able to install it on my phone and have some space left for other things (at least 5gb of available space should work)? If not then which ones among Pie and Oreo will be suitable for my phone and I didn't want to get lower than Android 8. I know that this question may be down voted or even closed but before doing so please answer my question. Thanks for reading.

Comment: A smartphone is not like a PC. You don't need similar hardware, you need a custom ROM built for exactly your device model only. A single different component inside your phone compared to the phone the ROM was built for can make the ROM unusable to you. Therefore you need a custom ROM built for your device, otherwise you can brick or destroy your phone.

Comment: Actually there is no custom ROM good my phone model. So I am using Motorola ROM.

Comment: The MotoX victara has an AMOLED, yours have an LCD hence the display controller will be with a chance next to 100% different. Thus this ROM will most likely not work. You need a ROM with at least the major hardware (CPU, display, storage, Wifi chip, mobile radio, ...) components exactly identical to your device. Otherwise you don't even have to try it.

Comment: So which ROM should I use?

Comment: If you don't find a ROM for your device then you have to stay with your current ROM or try to develop an ROM on your own if you have plenty of time and some development skills.